# Losing IP address "DHCPv4: grace period expired"

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, bridge

my laptop had poor wireless signal, so I hooked it up with an ethernet cable to an access point setup in bridge mode ('client mode' it's called on the AP, I believe). It works fine, but after some time, connection is lost and `ip a` doesn't report an IP address anymore. Restarting `network-manager` restores the connection.

In `syslog` I suspect these lines happen when connection is lost:

```
Dec  6 13:59:15 hart NetworkManager[153351]: <info>  [1701867555.3740] dhcp4 (enp1s0f1): state changed bound -> expire
Dec  6 13:59:15 hart NetworkManager[153351]: <info>  [1701867555.3771] device (enp1s0f1): DHCPv4: trying to acquire a new lease within 90 seconds
Dec  6 14:00:45 hart NetworkManager[153351]: <info>  [1701867645.4211] device (enp1s0f1): DHCPv4: grace period expired
```

I don't seem to find many clues about what is actually happening...

For now I'll try to write a script that tests network every couple of seconds and if it's down, does a restart of `network-manager`, but it'd be nice to have a proper solution.

Any ideas what's going on?

Best regards,
Vic